# zip objects created using the same iterables not equal. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, zip

Why two zip objects (made using same two iterables) aren't equal?

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
a = zip(list1, list2)
b = zip(list1, list2)
print(a == b)
```

The above code is printing `False`.
Shouldn't it give `True' since the zip objects are similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned `zip` object is an iterator. To be able to test the value equality of it, potentially the entire iterator would need to be walked, which would exhaust it, so you'd never be able to use it after. And if only part of the iterator was walked during the test, it would be left in a "difficult to determine state", so it wouldn't be usable there either.

I'm not sure if `zip` is considered to be a "user-defined class", but note this line in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> User-defined classes have `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods by default; with them, **all objects compare unequal (except with themselves)**

In theory they could have made a workaround that would allow equality testing of a `zip` object (in cases where the object that was zipped wasn't itself an iterator), but there was likely no need. I can't think of a scenario where you would need to test such a thing, and where comparing the object forced as a list isn't an option.

Comment: you are correct! We could check the equality by type conversion of the zip object (to either list or dict).
I didn't know that the zip object gets exhausted after being iterated through :(

Comment: @AvinashD That's the case with all iterators. Iterators only expose a `__next__` method; you can only get the next element of an iterator, and once you do, that changes the state of the iterator so you can only get the *next* element after that. There is no way to go "backward" or to restore the original state of an iterator without creating a new iterator, or creating a custom iterator that implements some non-standard behavior.